# Mock or avoid cognito authentication and group permissions for pytest

Tags: python, flask, pytest, amazon-cognito, pytest-mock

I have a flask app and I'm trying to implement pytest for the services I've built. All of the routes require cognito authentication or cognito group permissions. Is there a way I can mock or avoid cognito? From all the articles I've read online, nothing has helped me so far.

How would a pytest be implemented for the example below?

```
@app.route('/hello')
@cognito_auth_required
@cognito_group_permissions(["test"])
def hello():
    return 'Hello, World'
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this question while struggling to do the same thing. I was trying to patch out the decorators which was proving fruitless until I did some more digging. It turns out since the syntactic-sugar involving decorators is handled at runtime,you need to patch the library function out with a bypass function then reload your library under test in order for it to work.

I am using unittest rather than pytest. But this example, which returns a dict containing the logged in user's sub (we'll mock this too) should work:

src/controllers/some_module.py:

```
@cognito_auth_required
def my_example_function() -> dict:
    return {'your_sub' : current_cognito_jwt['sub']}
```

src/test/some_test.py

```
def mock_cognito_auth_required(fn):
    """
    This is a dummy wrapper of @cognito auth required, it passes-through 
    to the
    wrapped fuction without performing any cognito logic.

    """
    @wraps(fn)
    def decorator(*args, **kwargs):
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorator

def setUpModule():
    """
    Patches out the decorator (in the library) and reloads the module
    under test.
    """
    patch('flask_cognito.cognito_auth_required', mock_cognito_auth_required).start()
    reload(some_module)

@patch('src.controllers.some_module.current_cognito_jwt')
class TestSomeModule(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_my_example_function(self, mock_current_cognito_jwt):
        mock_current_cognito_jwt.__getitem__.return_value = 'test'
        response = some_module.my_example_function()
        self.assertEqual(response, {'your_sub': 'test'})
```

You should be able to do similar for cognito_group_permissions.